# How to avoid error messages in c++ caused by memory overflow

Tags: c++, memory, overflow, message

I have a C++ program which sometimes crashes because of memory overflow (max memory is 2GB, in some cases the program just needs more...).

I know that and I want the program to behave like that (because of reasons).

But the thing is, that windows opens a window with "Program stops working...".

How do I avoid these error messages and just get my application to shutdown without telling anything to the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you allocate memory using `new` you can try to catch [std::bad_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception

```
try
{
  buffer = new Type[HUGE_VAL];
}
catch (const std::bad_alloc& e)
{
  gracefulExit();
}
```

Remember, that `try` & `catch` can be somewhere at top level (in `main` for example), while allocation itself deep inside processing etc.

Still, reconsider doing your task in different way - split it into smaller tasks, or use some temporary files etc.

Comment: Or by using [`new (std::nothrow)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) and check for `nullptr`.

Comment: Antipattern above :) ^

Comment: @SergeyA care to elaborate on why that's an antipattern (other than the obvious OP-admitted fact that this question is asking how to implement an antipattern)?

Comment: @Dmitri one has to have really really good reasons to use `new (std::nothrow)` (like high cost of exceptions or some obsolete code/library). 'Out of memory' is an exceptional case and should be reported as exception :) It's also easier to propagate error via exception than via multiple `if (x != nullptr)` checks. Still - I'm not aware how OP is structuring his/hers program, so I think your comment completes my answer (especially as OP mentions that out-of-memory is expected, so exception is not necessity).

Comment: @Dmitri That's because it forces the responsibility of handling the memory allocation error to every part of the program responsible for memory allocation .Also, the response to such an error is usually the same so the program is subjected to a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Well, here a simple reason why. Standard allocator does not use nothrow new, so catching std::alloc is a must anyways. And once you have it, why bother with nothrow and than those omnipresent null checks?